# Basis of this vector space.?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let F denotes the set of sequences such that $u_{n}+u_{n+1}-u_{n+2}=0$. How to find a basis of this vector space? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, any such sequence is determined by $u_0$, $u_1$. A basis is:
$$\{(0,1,\cdots),(1,0,\cdots)\}.$$

Comment: you mean $span(u_{0}, u_{1})$ is a basis?

Comment: !!!!! ${\rm span}(u_0,u_1)$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$!

Comment: yes sure... all solutions  $v$ could be written as $v=(1,0)k_{0}u_{0} + (0,1) k_{1}u_{1}$ ? $k_0$ and $k_1$ are real numbers, thus a basis is $span((1,0),(0,1)))$ that's right?

Comment: A basis is a minimal generator system of a vector space. span(...) is a whole vector space.